# Fix accidental merge after using filter-branch

Tags: git

I followed the instructions [here](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/) to delete a binary file from my repo using filter-branch. The end of the article says

```
Make sure your collab uses rebase and not merge,
otherwise he will just reintroduce the file and the entire tainted history…
```

Unfortunately I read that bit *after* someone used merge on the repo. Now my history has a lot of duplicate commits:

```
commit 16c3838a7338c639421b9f244b572b6e23c0c3f7
Author: foo bar <foo@bar.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 7 13:20:28 2011 -0800

    update todo

commit 213ae8da0af8e92afa9808c3b16cecf0e1cc7a0c
Author: foo bar <foo@bar.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 4 21:14:08 2011 -0700

    update todo
```

And the binary file has been introduced in those duplicate commits. How to I get rid of the duplicate commits and the binary file?

Comment: If nothing helps, and you didn’t run the garbage collection yet, you can always undo what you did using `git reflog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go one revision back and do the rebase.